# Final Fantasy XIII-2 gameplay hours

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

How many hours of game play does Final Fantasy XIII-2 provide? This includes main story plus all the side quests and all unlocks.

I want to know because Final Fantasy 10 provides you with more than 100 hours of game play.

Blimey!

Comment: FFXIII also took about 100 hours to platinum.

Comment: Remember kids, if a question provides an answer with a link that could answer your question, it's a duplicate!

Comment: @Studoku No, we dupe ALL game completion to this one.  It's our one concession to these, due to their inherently subjective nature.

Comment: @Studoku It's not a duplicate, it was merely [decided that it would be better to dupe them](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/4288/51318) rather than close and delete them.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on a lot of things, but you might want to look for some sites collecting data about game completion times, such as [this one](http://www.howlongtobeat.com/game.php?id=3534).

Comment: Excellent! was looking for the same kind of data! so at the highest the game can go for 58 whooping hours!!!

Comment: Yes, it seems to get 100% complete you will need around 60 hours.

Comment: i got all unlockables and stuff in little more then 40 hours, this includes trophies.

Comment: @Stefto it would be a good idea to add your time to the site linked in my answer.

Comment: @sarmackie i don't really see why, but did it out of curiosity anyway >.<.

Comment: @Stefto just to give other gamers, such as GamDroid, some more insight into games they are interested in ;)

Answer (score 1):

It takes somewhere around 55 hours to fully complete the game, including all the trophies and everything.

Answer (score 0):

I did the Platinum in ~70 hours (I'm a PS3 user). On the [TrophyHuntersCommunity](http://www.psthc.fr/jeu-ps3/final-fantasy-xiii2/guide-trophees.htm) (French website) trophy guide for FFXIII-2, it's says "Temps nécessaire pour le platine : 65 Heures" which means "Time necessary for the Platinum : 65 hours"

Comment: We appreciate the incite but old questions like this don't need to be brought back up. I did the same thing when I was new here and then realized it gets you no where. haha